# Are Board of Education members immune to Death Feedback?

Tags: from-the-new-world

As we know from anime (I'm not familiar neither with manga or novel), Board of Education is responsible for disposing ("expelling from school/academy") of problematic student, who may turn to Akkis or Karma Demons. They may use variety of methods to do so - Bakenezumi assassins, nekodamashi, poisoned medicine etc. I'm sure that when they are ordering nekodamashi to kill student, they do realize, that they will be actual cause of death of another person.

We can see from several occasions (temple monk after killing living library, Saki after her plan to kill Akki was success), that even small allusion, that you are killing another human, may lead to heavy consequences, if not death.

So, my question is - are Board of Education members immune to Death Feedback? Numerous people were killed after their order, but it seems, that it does not affect any of Board of Education members at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow they've figured out that using additional objects or creatures to carry out the actual killing is a workaround which doesn't trigger the death feedback reaction. I suspect it was made clear at the time the death feedback was invented and introduced to people. There had to be *some* way to kill the deviants and possible mass murderers in case some genetic or other type of disorder prevented death feedback from preventing more deaths as intended.

Comment: Seems nice answer, but as for me, such backdoors are negating the very 
meaning of Death Feedback - ensuring that one human will not kill another. Well, anyway, I don't think there will be another explanation, so I suppose, we can mark this as certain mindset, which is necessary for Board members; similar to how Saki handled her Dead Feedback impact after tricking pseudo-Akki. Or they are not even "programmed" to have Death Feedback, but that would violate their rules even more.